# How do you add a link to a page number of your pdf in R Markdown?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I want to make a table of contents in my R markdown document which is clickable so that the viewer is redirected to the respective page number of the pdf. How do I make the table of contents clickable?

Comment: `toc: true` adds a clickable table of contents

Comment: Kind of, same solution, different problem though :P